# Is this the correct way of speaking to a "Content Manager" Class?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, oop

I am creating a silverlight site. I am currently breaking out my ideas into pieces of functionality. One of the idea's I have is the concept of a content manager. This is essentially a UI control with 4 regions. Top, Bottom, Right & Left. I also have a collection of objects that are considered "Menu Items". These are controls that function as a way to navigate around, similar to links.

The idea I have is to implement an IMenuItem interface. Among the standard pieces of information (Text, PageReference, etc) I was also going to hold a reference to the content manager. My idea behind this thinking is that I can pass the PageReference to a property on the ContentManager and then call a method which knows how to update the content manager accordingly.

Is this the best way of implementing this or is their some sort of pattern for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use a Silverlight navigation app, or RIA services business app? "Mainpage.xaml" does a lot of what you're asking for.

Comment: Good answer but I'm looking for a finer degree of customisation as every view could potentially have it's own menu which could open more views and more menus, this is why I would like to see if my implementation is sound.

Comment: In the end I went for this answer. More specifically the navigation framework. I re orged my classes and design to fit the framework and having browser intergration was worth it!